# Why allow commenting on closed questions?

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions

It seems that comments are allowed even on closed questions. Just wondering, is this is an oversight or is there any logic behind it?

I mean, closed means closed, doesn't it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Closed just means that you cannot add *answers*. It means that it is likely that the question does not belong.

But it doesn't *guarantee* that the question doesn't belong. For example, a poorly written question might be closed, only to be reopened after it is revised into a better state. Comments are allowed so that the author may be guided towards the steps that will improve the question to be reopened.

There is a separate question state, called "locked", which can only be applied by moderators. This prevents comments, as well as revisions and voting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense now

Comment: Well, that's what I call great answer.. well said! :-)